# binding issue when a directive in a ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

so this is how it looks like, and here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IPwDLT?p=preview)

```
parent scope 
   ng-repeat
       directive
```

in the directive there is an attribute is bi-directional binding with a variable in parent scope.

But this doesn't work as I wanted.(But I can understand why it doesn't work)

The reason is ngRepeat will create it's own scope, so once the variable is changed in directive, Angular add a variable in ngRepeat, but it leave the variable in parent unchanged.

I can do something like scope.$parent.$parent.variable to change the variable, but it is kinda not the idea in Angular.

How should I do ?

Moreover, if I change the repeated item in the items collection, the item can't be changed.

Because of the same reason above.

Comment: In case it helps try binding to non-primitive types (like an object). The binding should still work as expected even though there are child scopes being created unless you are binding to primitives. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12978044/1207991) for more info on it.

Comment: nope, that is not what I asked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: an $emit might do it but I don't like that answer.. feel like there's something better out there: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$emit

Comment: bubble the event, this works but I do feel the same with you

Comment: Thanks @Gloopy, in turns out you are right to the point. I should read that post more carefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT (again): It looks like the issue is you need to have *reference types* in your array, such as objects or arrays.

Gloopy was exactly right in the comments. The bi-directional binding wasn't working because it seems like Angular was creating copies of your primitives types (strings, numbers, etc) between the second scope pairing. So... when you have a nesting of bi-directionally bound primitive types between two scopes it's fine because it uses one instance, but when you nest it more than one deep, it creates a copy of the primitive and you're no longer updating the same instance.

[Here's a new demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3mHtcp)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { text: 'apples' },
    { text: 'bananas' },
    { text: 'oranges' }
  ];
  $scope.addItem = function(){
    $scope.items.push({ text: 'test' });
  };
});

app.directive('test', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      foo: '=foo'
    },
    template: '<div>{{foo}} <a ng-click="bar()">bar</a></div>',
    controller: function($scope){ 
      $scope.bar = function() {
        $scope.foo += '!';
      };
    }    
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for response :) http://plnkr.co/edit/HVy0QV I used your example, but the parent doesn't change. I think `scope.$parent` is the scope created by ngRepeat

Comment: I think I've figured it out. Gloopy's comment above was exactly right. You need to bind to references types.

Comment: Thank you ! I also found some discussions about this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/angular/copy$20reference$20primitives$20/angular/VD77QR1J6uQ/LN1YDBTJc2gJ

Comment: Once again sir @blesh, you saved my time.