# How to create unique ng-form tags on a form with ng-repeat in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a form part of which is a table that loops over a list of objects and for each object allows the user to check/uncheck attributes. The rest of the form works fine but I am having trouble setting the ng-model attribute on the checkboxes.

Here's what I have:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Objects and Fields</td>
            <td>Createable</td>
            <td>Deleteable</td>
            <td>Readable</td>
            <td>Updateable</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="object in myAppObjects">
          <td>
            {{object.name}}&nbsp;{{object.id}}
            <input type="checkbox" name="app_access_{{object.id}}" ng-model="app_access" value="false">
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

At first I tried setting the ng-model="app_access_{{object.id}}" so that I would have a unique ng-model for each cell. This caused the table row to be repeated several dozen times. Each of those empty cells will also have a check box. There will be five check boxes for each object and several objects in the form at a given time. I'll need to be able to access each check box (or better yet a list of the checked ones) in the controller.

Comment: I don't think you can use Angular expressions to name a field element.  See https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/v5lK1y8-HXQ/discussion

Comment: using angular expressions for a name works fine. It's just using them for the ng-model attribute that causes trouble. I think Max's answer below points me in the right direction. I'll have to experiment some more.

Comment: In my experience, it unfortunately doesn't always work fine.  Here's a fiddle showing a problem when using an Angular expression for a name together with Angular form validation:  http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/teZKX/  Inspecting the input element, the Angular expression appears to be evaluated, but the Angular validation stuff doesn't seem to recognize it.  Since this case doesn't work, I personally don't use Angular expressions in field names with any form controls. YMMV.  Maybe with checkboxes it works fine.  BTW, the name attribute is optional with Angular checkboxes -- you may not need it.

Comment: It's true in this case the name is an unrelated issue.

Comment: Over the weekend I wrote a directive that uses radio buttons, and I ended up using angular expressions for the field names. :-P  So much for "I don't use Angular expressions in field names with any form controls."  I guess I'll now have to say "I don't use Angular expressions in field names if those names are used with Angular form validation."  Thanks for expanding/correcting my understanding of this.

Comment: Sounds like it might be good to avoid in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ngRepeat creates a new (child) scope for each item, creating new ng-models (that are tied to those new scopes) for the items will not work because those models/data will only be accessible inside those inner scopes.  We can't write a controller function to access those inner/child scopes.  It is better to reference something in myAppObjects for the models (like @Max suggests in his second example).

If myAppObjects looks something like this:

```
$scope.myAppObjects = [
  {id: 1, cb1: true,  cb2: false, cb3: true, cb4: true,  cb5: false },
  {id: 2, cb1: false, cb2: false, cb3: true, cb4: false, cb5: true  },
```

You could write your ng-repeat like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="appObj in myAppObjects">
    <td>{{appObj.id}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="appObj.cb1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="appObj.cb2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="appObj.cb3"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="appObj.cb4"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="appObj.cb5"></td>
</tr>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/AvGKj/

Bottom line: we need to have the checkbox models defined in/on the parent scope (in my fiddle, MyCtrl's $scope), and not in/on the ngRepeat inner/child scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you are iterating over a collection using `ng-repeat` then the the items that you display and edit are the individual members of the collection. So if you have an array of strings that are being edited by the `ng-repeat` you would do

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
  <input ng-model="item" />
</div>
```

Or if is a list of objects you are iterating over you would do

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in list">
  <input ng-model="obj.item" />
</div>
```

Comment: Note, the first example above ("item in list") won't work if the items in the list array are primitives (e.g., an array of strings won't work). Two-say data binding will be broken.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977894/what-is-the-angularjs-way-to-databind-many-inputs