# No access to scope variables directly inside ng-template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I recently moved some repeated markup into ng-template blocks, and I noticed that inside the blocks, I do not get direct access to scope variables, but I can still call scope functions.

For instance, consider the following markup:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="toggle-button.html">
    <button ng-click="toggleFlag()">I Toggle the Flag</button>
    <button ng-click="flag = !flag">I Do Nothing</button>
</script>
<span ng-include="'toggle-button.html'"></span>
The flag is {{flag}}
```

Paired with the following script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("myController", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.flag = true;

    $scope.toggleFlag = function(){
        $scope.flag = !$scope.flag;
    }
}])
```

Live JS Fiddle of this behavior:
http://jsfiddle.net/uM4Ss/

The first button works, the second does not. Can somebody please answer why this is the case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**ngInclude** creates new child scope.

You should use `$parent` if you want to access parent scope variables.
http://jsfiddle.net/mX7v2/

Also you can define controller inside template to share the same scope between controller and a template.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to `why` this is the case? Do templates get their own sub-scope?

Comment: @StephenRios ngInclude directive does

Answer (score 4):

You are [binding to a primitive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).  Bind to an object instead, and the binding will work in the child scope:  http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/uM4Ss/2/

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="toggle-button.html">
    <button ng-click="toggleFlag()">I Toggle the Flag</button>
    <button ng-click="flags.flag = !flags.flag">I Do Nothing</button>
</script>
<span ng-include="'toggle-button.html'"></span>
The flag is {{flags.flag}}
```

script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("myController", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.flags=  {
        flag: true
    };

    $scope.toggleFlag = function(){
        $scope.flags.flag = !$scope.flags.flag;
    }
}])
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977894/what-is-the-angularjs-way-to-databind-many-inputs/13782671#13782671