# AngularJS Radio button not binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am a complete beginner at using Angular.js and I've run into an issue with data binding in a radio button situation. The related HTML code looks like this:

```
<label class="options_box" ng-repeat="item in item_config_list.item_config"> 
    <input type="radio" name="config" ng-model="selectedConfig" ng-value="item"> 
        {{ item.item }}
    </input>
</label>
```

and controller is

```
App.controller('controller', function App ($scope, $http) {

    $.getJSON('res/prop/configs.json', function(data) {
    $scope.item_config_list = data;

});
```

json file looks like this:

```
{
    "item_config": [
    {
        "name": "Config1",
        "configNr": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Config2",
        "configNr": "2"
    },
]
}
```

How do I make the name property of the selected item from the radio list go into the "selectedConfig" object? I am later referring to the selectedConfig object to fetch data from a backend.

I might also add that the duplication of radio buttons is working - as is the labelling of the buttons. They are named properly, they just aren't conferring the intended value to the intended object.

Edit: Problem solved! I refactored above HTML code to

```
<label class="options_box" ng-repeat="item in item_config_list.item_config"> 
    <input type="radio" name="config" ng-model="$parent.selectedConfig" ng-value="item.name"> 
        {{ item.name }}
    </input>
</label>
```

Comment: Your `$.getJSON` is outside of your controller. Add it in your Controller

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted from my IDE and I have another one of these properties that I didn't feel was needed in the question so the first }); was just an artifact.

Comment: Can you provide the json you are getting from service ?

Comment: I have added the related json file @Vaibhav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to change the `ng-value` binding:

```
<input type="radio" name="config" ng-model="selectedConfig" ng-value="item.item"> 
    {{ item.item }}
</input>
```

That should then bind the name string in `item.item` to your scope's `selectedConfig`

Slight confusion from your `ng-repeat` objects being called `item` and the first property of each object in that collection is also called `item`

UPDATE:

From the fiddle you provided I have a working example for you to look at:

https://jsfiddle.net/sc622go8/

The underlying issue was that the `ng-repeat` creates a child scope, so to refer to the `selectedConfig` variable, you need to use `$parent.selectedConfig`:

```
<input type="radio" name="config" ng-model="$parent.selectedConfig" ng-value="item.item"> 
    {{ item.item }}
</input>
```

Comment: I tried adding a

    console.log(selectedConfig) 

into the script to fetch from the backend and it's "undefined", even after I added the extra 
    item.item

Comment: It is referring to the first property of the items - would that be an issue?

Comment: Literally solved it at the same time - thank you! It was the $parent in ng-model I was missing.

Comment: no worries :) $parent is easy to forget about in ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

Please use different "name" attribute for all the input fields in being generated using the ng-repeat.

Something like below :

```
<input type="radio" name="config{{$index}}" ng-model="selectedConfig" ng-value="item.item"> 
    {{ item.item }}
</input>
```

Please look at the following plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/RQQi5Fo9FzM409qKHwjG?p=preview

I hope this will do the trick

Comment: The name attribute of the radio buttons decide which ones can be checked together - this would mean that I can check all of the buttons in the intended group? Sorry if I'm not getting something but how would that help?

Comment: "ng-model" holds the value of the object which has to be same for all the radio buttons(so only one radio button will be checked and will be assigned the value that is provided in ng-value) whereas when the "name" attribute's value is same then it creates conflicts and thus doesn't bind the value with the model.

Comment: When I tried adding the {{$index}}, it allowed multiple radio buttons to be selected.

Also, isn't ng-model referring to the target of the data binding? so in pseudocode: { when radio button is checked } send { ng-value } to {ng-model}

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this ?

Comment: Were you able to replicate it in the fiddle or plnkr ? Would be great if you can provide the same. :)

Comment: Little late though :) And yes ng-repeat creates its own child scope and it follows the prototypical inheritance. So to access an object outside the scope of ng-repeat, you need to have an object with '.' notation. For more information please look at this topic please follow the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977894/what-is-the-angularjs-way-to-databind-many-inputs/13782671#13782671